# Remove last item from array and add it to the front of another array

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code for back and forward buttons.

I want the:

**Back button**

- To remove the last element from array `currentFolderFlow`
- Add this element to the front of another array `backFolders`

**Forward Button**

- To add the last element of `backFolders` to `currentFolderFlow`
- Remove this element from `backFolders`

My code: (Somehow nothing happens when I click the back button)

```html
<script>

let currentFolderFlow = ["Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3", "Element 4"]
    let backFolders = []

const back = () => {
        const lastFolder = currentFolderFlow[currentFolderFlow.length - 1]
        backFolders = [...backFolders, lastFolder]
        currentFolderFlow = currentFolderFlow.slice(0, -1)
    }

    const forward = () => {
        const lastFolder = backFolders[backFolders.length - 1]
        currentFolderFlow = [...currentFolderFlow, lastFolder]
        backFolders = backFolders.slice(0, -1)
    }
</script>

<button class="btn hover:bg-base-300 bg-transparent border-0 {currentFolderFlow.length === 1 ? 'btn-disabled': 'text-base-content'}" on:click={() => back()}>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M10.5 19.5L3 12m0 0l7.5-7.5M3 12h18" />
                </svg>
            </button>

            <button class="btn hover:bg-base-300 bg-transparent border-0 {backFolders.length === 0 ? 'btn-disabled' : 'text-base-content'}" on:click={() => forward()}>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M13.5 4.5L21 12m0 0l-7.5 7.5M21 12H3" />
                </svg>
            </button>
```

Comment: You should checkout Javascript's [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) and [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) array methods

Comment: on:click is used to bind a function to the click when using svelte. Are you using a framework or is this vanilla js?

Comment: @MarkosTh09 I'm using sveltekit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **pop**

   The pop() method removes the last element of an array.
2. **push**

   The push() method adds new items to the end of an array.

*If you want to remove first element of array use*

3. **shift**

   The shift() method removes the first item of an array.

```js
let currentFolderFlow = ["Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3", "Element 4"]
let backFolders = []

const back = () => {
  //adding last element of currentFolderFlow to first of backFolder
  backFolders = [currentFolderFlow[currentFolderFlow.length - 1], ...backFolders]
  // removing that element from currentFolderFlow
  currentFolderFlow.pop()
  console.log(backFolders, currentFolderFlow)
}

const forward = () => {
  //adding last element of backFolders to currentFolderFlow
  currentFolderFlow.push(backFolders[backFolders.length - 1])
  // removing that element from currentFolderFlow 
  backFolders.pop()
  console.log(backFolders, currentFolderFlow)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="back()"> < back</button>
<button onclick="forward()"> forward ></button>
```

I think there is a logical mistake that you mentioned in forward. In forward, add the first element of `backFolders` to `currentFolderFlow` to get the original array. If you want like this, change forward function like following

```js
let currentFolderFlow = ["Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3", "Element 4"]
let backFolders = []

const back = () => {
  //adding last element of currentFolderFlow to first of backFolder
  backFolders = [currentFolderFlow[currentFolderFlow.length - 1], ...backFolders]
  // removing that element from currentFolderFlow
  currentFolderFlow.pop()
  console.log(backFolders, currentFolderFlow)
}

const forward = () => {
  //adding first element of backFolders to currentFolderFlow
  currentFolderFlow.push(backFolders[0])
  // removing that element from currentFolderFlow 
  backFolders.shift()
  console.log(backFolders, currentFolderFlow)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="back()"> < back</button>
<button onclick="forward()"> forward ></button>
```

### Add some more condition to buttons

1. Disable back button when `currentFolderFlow` is empty
2. Disable forward button when `backFolders` is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
let array1 = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4'];
let array2 = [];
console.log('--------Default---------');
console.log('Array 1 :', array1);
console.log('Array 2 :',array2);
const back = () =>{
    let item = array1.pop();
    array2.push(item);

    console.log('--------Back---------');
    console.log('Array 1 :', array1);
    console.log('Array 2 :',array2);
}

const forward = () => {
    let item = array2.pop();
    array1.push(item);
    console.log('--------Forward---------');
    console.log('Array 1 :',array1);
    console.log('Array 2 :',array2);
}
back();
forward();
```

Output:

```
--------Default---------
Array 1 : [ 'item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4' ]
Array 2 : []
--------Back---------
Array 1 : [ 'item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3' ]
Array 2 : [ 'item 4' ]
--------Forward---------
Array 1 : [ 'item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4' ]
Array 2 : []
```